# Prevent Growth of Subreport

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to prevent a subreport from growing and pushing other objects off the page. Normally, I would set `CanGrow` to `false`, however that property does not exist on the subreport. I have set `CanGrow` to `false` on each object inside the subreport, however the issue is too many rows, not too large objects.

Is there a way to cut off a subreport after a set number of pixels or even repeated rows?

I am using v13.2.

Comment: `KeepTogether` is also set to `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress subreport does not support CanGrow property and the height of its content is completely defined by the subReport's content.  So, the only solution to reduce the height of a SubReport is to reduce the height of its underlying Report.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but thanks. Is there a way to trick the subreport by putting in a certain band by itself? (header, footer, etc)